# Add unique names for map markers inside a for loop Android

Tags: android, google-maps, loops, unique, marker

I need to create multiple map markers loaded from database. And I need to delete them when i clicked on them. So I think I need an unique name (or place_id) for each marker to do that.(if any one has a better idea suggest me). But how can I give an unique marker name inside a loop.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

for (int x = 0; x < jsonarray.length(); x++) {

 JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(x);

 places_id = jsonobject.getInt("places_id");

 status = jsonobject.getInt("status");

 category = jsonobject.getString("category");

 date = jsonobject.getString("date");

 time = jsonobject.getString("time");


 Marker uniquename = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,long)).title("marker")));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have naming restrictions, what about concatenating the marker name with your iterator variable? i.e:

```
for (int x = 0; x < jsonarray.length(); x++) {
 Marker uniquename = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,long)).title("Marker " + String.valueOf(x))));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can i use something to **uniquename** instead using x variable in title. I do not like to show any numbers in the title.

Comment: Can you define what would you prefer to show as title?

Comment: I need to show only text on the title but not with a number. If there is a way to show only the text in the title hiding  String.valueOf(x) that would be also fine.

Comment: If you have no defined criteria on what to show to the user, there could be two ways about it: 1) If you have control over the database/data source that's returning the data, perhaps you can define a name attribute there  *would personally prefer this*  2) You can arbitrarily define a method that returns a unique string based on each object's unique attribute values; i.e: if ( object.id == xxx && category.equals("xxx") ) set a name String value = "yyy" , and then construct a map with values representing your json array objects with keys being the output of this method.

Comment: ...This way you'd have a mapping between the unique names based on the criteria you defined and your json array objects. Let me know if you'd need further clarification, and if you found the answer of help please mark it as accepted :) good luck!